# How to access azure web app console or kudu console locally using putty or mac terminal?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-cli

I have hosted a web app in azure and I am able to use console through kudu console or azure dashboard but for better development workflow, accessing it through mac terminal is essential.

I don't know how to access azure's web console (not azure server management console) through mac terminal.

Its not linux vm. Its default web app using windows.

Comment: SSH would be a good start... But you'd probably need a public key

Comment: @cricket_007  Yeah but with Azure, I can't figure out where to get ssh

Comment: Kudu Console is a web app? Then you need to open that port to the external internet

Comment: In other words, the Mac terminal won't work for accessing a web app

Comment: Is there any way to connect to server using mac terminal or I have to use online kudu console or azure console to run my git commands

Comment: Your question says nothing about Git... Also, I don't know if the Azure windows VMs are even running an SSH server for you to connect to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

On Mac, if you want to access Kudu Console, you could use a browser open `http://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net`. But you could not do it on mac terminal.

On Mac terminal, you could call Kudu API to manage your web app, see this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API).

On Mac terminal, you also could use [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to manage your web app.

Comment: Kudu API sounds helpful. Thanks for that. Though I saw that documentation earlier but didn't notice that part.

Comment: You could SSH proxy the web ui, but still using a browser to connect.